# Failed to Inflate error tring to run android app

Tags: android, android-inflate

I tried the google speech recognition sample code, however, the app crashed and logcat reported the Failed to inflate exception.

Here is my code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
/* 
 * Copyright (C) 2008 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.example.audiphone;

import com.example.audiphone.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Sample code that invokes the speech recognition intent API.
 */
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private static final int VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;

    private ListView mList;

    /**
     * Called with the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Inflate our UI from its XML layout description.
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Get display items for later interaction
        Button speakButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_speak);

        mList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Check to see if a recognition activity is present
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(
                new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH), 0);
        if (activities.size() != 0) {
            speakButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        } else {
            speakButton.setEnabled(false);
            speakButton.setText("Recognizer not present");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handle the click on the start recognition button.
     */
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.btn_speak) {
            startVoiceRecognitionActivity();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Fire an intent to start the speech recognition activity.
     */
    private void startVoiceRecognitionActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Speech recognition demo");
        startActivityForResult(intent, VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    /**
     * Handle the results from the recognition activity.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Fill the list view with the strings the recognizer thought it could have heard
            ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                    RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            mList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    matches));
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Here is my **layout/activity_main.xml**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_speak"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="@string/point2speak" />
    <List
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.audiphone"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.audiphone.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Update:
here is the logcat output.

```
05-27 21:58:38.778: E/ActivityThread(23210):    at com.example.audiphone.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:53)
05-27 21:58:38.778: E/ActivityThread(23210): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.List" on path: /data/app/com.example.audiphone-1.apk
05-27 21:58:38.878: E/AndroidRuntime(23210): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.audiphone/com.example.audiphone.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class List
05-27 21:58:38.878: E/AndroidRuntime(23210):    at com.example.audiphone.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:53)
05-27 21:58:38.878: E/AndroidRuntime(23210): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.List" on path: /data/app/com.example.audiphone-1.apk
05-27 21:58:56.295: E/ActivityThread(23372):    at com.example.audiphone.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:53)
05-27 21:58:56.295: E/ActivityThread(23372): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.List" on path: /data/app/com.example.audiphone-1.apk
05-27 21:58:56.315: E/AndroidRuntime(23372): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.audiphone/com.example.audiphone.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class List
05-27 21:58:56.315: E/AndroidRuntime(23372):    at com.example.audiphone.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:53)
05-27 21:58:56.315: E/AndroidRuntime(23372): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.List" on path: /data/app/com.example.audiphone-1.apk
```

Comment: Please post your logcat output.

Answer (score 0):

In your activity_main.xml, you use

```
<List
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
```

Do you mean ListView? The logcat said no class found for android.view.List, I think you were trying to use ListView.

Comment: Yes, it should be ListView. Thanks.